# windows 7 rtm vhd file

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vhd

How can I install Windows 7 rtm vhd files in an existing windows xp machine?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about VHD files, you do not install this. A VHD image is a complete installation of Windows that is ready to run in a virtual machine.

The easiest thing you can do in Windows XP is to [download Microsoft Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/virtual-pc-2007.aspx), and then simply copy all the VHD files to a directory and either create a new virtual machine pointing to the VHD or run the configuration file (It depends what you downloaded).

You should then be running Windows 7 virtually within your Windows XP installation.